# Decoding optional List of objects in RealmSwift class

Tags: swift, list, realm, codable

I am trying initialize Codable List of objects in Realm class, the problem is that the app crashes when server return empty list

this is the code for initializing List

```swift
class TicketDetails: Object, Decodable {

    var working: [WorkingHour]?
    var workingHours = List<WorkingHour>()

    public convenience required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let workingArray = try container.decodeIfPresent(Array<WorkingHour>.self, forKey: .working) {
            working = workingArray
            workingHours.append(objectsIn: workingArray)
        } else {
            working = nil
            workingHours = List.init()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be missing something but why are you doing this? When a TicketDetails object is loaded, the [List](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html) property will be populated with WorkingHours. List is the container type in Realm used to define to-many relationships. It looks like you're trying to overwrite that?

Comment: I do that because working hours array might be nil from server

Comment: It will only be nil if there's well, nothing in the list. Once objects are added it won't be nil. It unclear what you are doing this as it defeats the purpose of having a managed List property. If you are going to just manually populate it, make it an array. Also, it's unclear why this object needs to be decodable. IMO, making an Object like this Encodable/Decodable ends up just being a lot more work - especially since these are managed, live updating objects in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

A few oddities here.

`TicketDetails` is declared as a Realm object, but includes an array, which is just a duplicate of a Realm List property. Why? Remove the array. List needs to be a let, and remove the entire else clause as that won't work.

```
class TicketDetails: Object, Decodable 
{
  let workingHours = List<WorkingHour>()

  public convenience required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    self.init()
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    if let workingArray = try container.decodeIfPresent(Array<WorkingHour>.self, forKey: .working) 
    {
        workingHours.append(objectsIn: workingArray)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Loading data from json in this section mention that if data is nil for required property realm will throws exception and workinghour array in my case return as nil empty array in some cases so I Do not think this is the best solution

Comment: Yes, that's true. There are solutions for that around SO, but you're probably right. Hopefully the rest of the answer sorts your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's more convenient and working solutions with the latest version of RealmCocoa 4.4.1. Don't forget define CodingKeys enum if network responses different than your models.

```
class TicketDetails: Object, Decodable {
    var working = List<[WorkingHour]>()
    var workingHours = List<WorkingHour>()

    public convenience required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.working = try container.decodeIfPresent(List<WorkingHour>.self, forKey: .working) ?? List<WorkingHour>.self
        self.workingHours = try container.decodeIfPresent(List<WorkingHour>.self, forKey: .working) ?? List<WorkingHour>.self
    }
}
```